# How to get older version of opencv

Tags: aptitude, opencv

This fails:

```
sudo apt-get -t=2.3.1 install libopencv
```

Is there a way to figure put which command I have to type to get 2.3.1 running?

The default on Ubuntu 13.04 is 2.4

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the DEB installer file for version 2.3 and install it manually. Or through Ubuntu software center even (by doubleclicking the DEB).

2.3 can be found here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/precise/opencv (debian) or from the official website: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/ (sources).